# Testing with taiko: assert false

Tags: testing, assert, gauge

I am working with taiko and gauge right now and have several asserts as e.g.

`assert.ok(text("example").exists())`

But now I delete some text parts and want to check that the text really is deleted. 
I tried

`assert.equal(text("example").exists(), false)`

but that fails. 
I suppose that `exists()` doesn't return booleans since `assert.equal(text("example").exists(), true)`also fails, while the above `.ok` is correct.

Is there any function like `assert.notOk(text("example").exists())`?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`text("example").exists()` waits for the text and fails if the text is not available on the page after specific interval of time.

Try using `exists` function as follows

```
text("example").exists(0,0) // i.e. (retryInterval, retryTimeout)
```

This will check the page immediately and return a boolean.

Comment: I've tried this solution with no luck.

assert.ok(await text(str).exists(0,0))

Answer (score 0):

You can add the expected result (`true` or `false`) to your `assert`:

```
assert.ok(text("example").exists(), false)
```

This will result in a `true` if the search pattern does not exists.